# PagerSlidingTabStrip (com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip ) how can i add tabs dynamically at the runtime?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am using `com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip` in my application to render several tabs in my application. My requirement is that I need to add more tabs when a user clicks something, or on swipe to the last-right end of the Tabs. I reviewed almost all of the stackoverflow threads but couldn't find any proper help.

Here is what i am doing - Layout file (XML) :

```
<LinearLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
        app:pstsTextAllCaps="true"
        app:pstsIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/theme_color">
    </com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment :

```
public class MandiEntryAddTabFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private View view;
    private PagerSlidingTabStrip mTabs;
    private MyFragmentPagerAdapter mAdapter;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mandi_add, container, false);

            if (viewPager == null) {
                viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            }
            getBaseActivity().setTitle("Material Entry");
            FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
            viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter = new   MyFragmentPagerAdapter(manager));
            mTabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            mTabs.setViewPager(viewPager);
        }
        return view;

    }

    class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        private ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int item) {
            Fragment fragment = null;

            if (item == 0) {
                fragment = new MandiEntryFragment();
            } else if (item == 1) {
                fragment = new MandiEntryFarmerFragment();
            } else if (item == 2) {
                fragment = new MandiEntryFarmerFragment();
            } else if (item == 3) {
                fragment = new MandiEntryFarmerFragment();
            } else if (item == 4) {
                fragment = new MandiEntryFarmerFragment();
            }/* else if (item == 5) {
                fragment = new MandiEntryFarmerFragment();
                new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()).addTab("test " + (mAdapter.getCount() + 1));
            }*/
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            String title = new String();
            if (position == 0) {
                title = "Entry";
            } else if (position == 1) {
                title = "Farmer 1";
            } else if (position == 2) {
                title = "Farmer 2";
            } else if (position == 3) {
                title = "Farmer 3";
            } else if (position == 4) {
                title = "Farmer 4";
                tabs.get(position);
            } /*else if (position == 5) {
                title = "Add";

                public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) { return   tabs.get(position);
                }

            }*/
            return title;
        }

        public void addTab(String tab) {
            tabs.add(tab);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            mTabs.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void fetchAndShowData() {
        Fragment fragment = getActiveFragment(viewPager);
        if (fragment != null) {
            ((BaseFragment) fragment).fetchAndShowData();
        }
    }
}
```

And the error I get is :

> E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{c2c.cloud4things.com/com.cloud4things.c2c.CommunityHomeActivity}:
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 0

Also on the `getPageTitle` and `onCreateView` functions of the above fragment.
I can understand that there is some problem with the `getCount` method. But I don't know how to do it. Please Assist me. Leads are appreciated. Thanks in Advance!